# Using Jquery to append div index within same div

Tags: jquery, indexing, append, each

I have a basic set-up like this:

```
<div class="stop">
    <span class="point"></span>
</div>
<div class="stop">
    <span class="point"></span>
</div>
```

and I would like to append the index of div.stop within the nested span.point of each, like this:

```
<div class="stop">
    <span class="point">1</span>
</div>
<div class="stop">
    <span class="point">2</span>
</div>
```

This is the jquery I'm using, but it's not working:

```
$("div.stop").each(function() {
    var stopNumber = $("div.stop").index(this);
    $("div.stop span.point").append(stopNumber);
});
```

Thanks in advance for any tips or suggestions.

-Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the `index` call, `.each` supplies the index as a parameter to the callback:

```
$("div.stop").each(function(n) {
    $('span.point', this).append(n + 1);
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/55ABr/

Comment: Should use text() instead of append() - otherwise good answer.

Comment: true - I was too lazy to fix the OP's code there.  He may have a good reason for using `.append()`.

Comment: thanks! so the (n + 1) is taking the index of each div.stop? or is it just using .each to count how many times its running? Also, what does ('span.point', this) accomplish?

Comment: technically it's the index within the array returned by `$('div.point')`, but it's the same thing.  `$(selector, parent)` restricts the selector to nodes below `parent`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select the point within the div `stop`.  Try this:

```
$("div.stop").each(function() {
    var stopNumber = $("div.stop").index(this);
    $("span.point", this).append(stopNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("div.stop").each(function(i, el) {     
    $("span.point", this).text(i+1); 
});
```